# tkz-graph: Edge's beginning doesn't connect to vertex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph

In this example, the edges don't connect to the vertex it comes from.
I'm using `tkz-graph`, and use `\tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[pos]` to give an arrow head to the edges.
I modified the value of `\VertexInterMinSize` and `\VertexDistance`, but it doesn't make the vertex slightly bigger so to touch the edge.
Making the vertex bigger by modifying `\VertexSmallMinSize` doesn't work either.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
        \renewcommand*{\VertexInterMinSize}{1mm}
        \renewcommand*{\VertexDistance}{1mm}
        \renewcommand*{\VertexSmallMinSize}{1mm}
        
        \Vertex[x=-2,y=0,Lpos=90,style = {font=\footnotesize},L=a]{a}
        
        \Vertex[x=0,y=0,Lpos=90,style = {font=\footnotesize,align=center},L={b\\b}]{b}
        \Vertex[x=3,y=-1,Lpos=0,style = {font=\footnotesize},L=c]{c}
        \Vertex[x=0,y=-2,Lpos=-90,style = {font=\footnotesize},L=d]{d}
        \Vertex[x=3,y=-3,Lpos=-90,style = {font=\footnotesize},L=e]{e}
        
        \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[post]
        \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {draw opacity=0, fill opacity=0, text opacity=1,font=\footnotesize}}
        \Edge[label=1, labelstyle={above}](b)(a)
        
        \Edge[label=2, labelstyle={above}](b)(c)
        \Edge[label=3, labelstyle={above,xshift=2mm}](b)(e)
        \Edge[label=4, labelstyle={left}](b)(d)
        \Edge[label=5, labelstyle={below,xshift=-2mm}](d)(e)
        \Edge[label=6, labelstyle={right}](c)(e)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead `\tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[pos]`, I changed it to `\tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[->]`, and now the edges connect to the out vertex.

Comment: The reason this works is that the `post` style is defined by `tkz-graph` as `post/.style={->,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth',semithick}`. As you can see the start of the line is shortened by 1pt, causing the gap. Hence, you could also do for example `\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={post, shorten <=0}}` to remove the shortening.